# Expected Identifier Code Error when running script?

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, copy, backup

I got this script off the technet website, but I get an error when I try to execute it on my Windows 7 machine. I am completely new to scripting, but I wonder if this was made for an older OS and needs a bit of changing for Windows 7? I'm quite sure the guy who wrote it up tested it.

I get the Windows Script Host Error as follows:
Line: 1
Char: 10
Error: Expected Identifier
Code: 800A03F2
Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error.

Here's the script:

```
Function New-BackUpFolder($destinationFolder)
{
 $dte = get-date
 $dte = $dte.tostring() -replace "[:\s/]", "."
 $backUpPath = "$destinationFolder" + $dte
 $null = New-Item -path $backUpPath -itemType directory
 New-Backup $dataFolder $backUpPath $backUpInterval
} #end New-BackUpFolder

Function New-Backup($dataFolder,$backUpPath,$backUpInterval)
{
 "backing up $dataFolder... check $backUppath for your files"
 Get-Childitem -path $dataFolder -recurse |
 Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge (get-date).addDays(-$backUpInterval) } |
 Foreach-Object { copy-item -path $_.FullName -destination $backUpPath -force }
} #end New-BackUp

# *** entry point to script ***

$backUpInterval = 1
$dataFolder = "C:\fso"
$destinationFolder = "C:\BU\"
New-BackupFolder $destinationFolder
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Looking at line: 1, char: 10, I would guess that 'New' is a protected word. Try changing the names of the methods to not be prefixed with 'New-'.

Comment: Please revise your subject line so the question will be useful to future visitors to the site. Otherwise, it is "too localized".

Answer (score 2):

that's actually Powershell and not VB script. You need to run the code inside Powershell for this to work.

This link looks pretty good for a brief introduction if you haven't done PS before.

http://www.abstrys.com/files/BeginningPowershellScripting.html

Comment: I think you kindly for that answer, I am absolutely swamped at work and I had no time to suddenly learn scripting just for this, I think I can figure it out from here, I just needed a kick in the right direction.